# Create Badge system using php multiquery and output JSON Array To Android studio

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create a badge incentive system in my android app.
I have created 9 queries and using the SQL multi-query call in PHP.
Queries were created to output 1 or 0 to make it easier to handle the java side via "android studio".
These 1s and 0s will change a default null badge to an earned badge.
What is the easiest way to handle this?
I initially want to create just a 3X3 array or list that can change views easier. Not sure if the outputs of the array must be a variable and then made to an array.
I am currently using a frame layout to change between views in android in a large project.

```
if(isset($_POST['BadgeLayout'])){
    $UserID = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['UserID']);
    echo ($UserID);
```

//badge determined by count 1 & 10

```
    //Leve1Badge1 
    //if count 1 user earns badge- user connected 1` plant
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(PlantID) FROM Plant WHERE UserID = '$UserID';"

    //Level1Badge2
    //check if against stock if not = to stock url user earns badge
    //does not equal stock image urls
    $sql . = "SELECT GoogleProfileURL FROM User WHERE UserID = '$UserID';"

    // User has fertlized their plants atleast twice
    //Level1Badge3
    $sql . = "SELECT COUNT(wofe.PlantID+p.Nickname+wofe.Occurrence+wofe.EventType)
    FROM WaterOrFertilizeEvent AS wofe
    JOIN Plant AS p
    WHERE p.UserID = '$UserID'
    AND p.PlantID = wofe.PlantID;"

    //Level2Badge1
    //If count = 1 ----> User has both GardenLocationLat and GardenLocationLng enabled

    $sql . = "SELECT COUNT(GardenLocationLng+GardenLocationLat) FROM User WHERE UserID='$UserID' AND GardenLocationLng IS NOT NULL AND GardenLocationLat IS NOT NULL;"

    //Level2Badge2

    // if value count = 0 ---->All user plant id are  FeedingTrackingEnabled
    $sql . = "SELECT COUNT(PlantID) FROM Plant WHERE UserID = '$UserID' AND FeedingTrackingEnabled IS NULL;"

    //Level2Badge3
    //if all plants weather tracking enable count = 0 ----> All user PlantID are WeatherTrackingEnabled 
    $sql . = "SELECT COUNT(PlantID) FROM Plant WHERE UserID = '$UserID' AND WeatherTrackingEnabled IS NOT NULL;"





   //Level3Badge1
   //if true user earns badge
   // exact species  is still needed cactus as place holder
   $sql . = "SELECT COUNT(UserID) FROM Plant WHERE UserID = '$UserID') AND Species = 'Florida Roseling'; "

   //Level3Badge2
   //If plantID count = 10 ---> UserID has 10 plants
   $sql = "SELECT COUNT(PlantID) FROM Plant WHERE UserID = '$UserID';"

   //Level3Badge3
   //If User water all plant id a consecutive of 100x----->user earns badge
   $sqk . = "SELECT COUNT(wofe.EventType)
   FROM WaterOrFertilizeEvent AS wofe
   JOIN Plant AS p
   WHERE p.UserID = '$Userid'
   AND p.PlantID = wofe.PlantID;
   AND wofe.EventType = 'W';"


   $result = mysqli_multi_query($conn, $sql) or die("Error in checking per badges per user " . mysqli_error($conn));

    if (mysqli_multi_query($conn, $sql)) {
      do {
        // Store first result set
        if ($result = mysqli_store_result($conn)) {
          while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
            printf("%s\n", $row[0]);
          }
          mysqli_free_result($result);
        }
        // if there are more result-sets, the print a divider
        if (mysqli_more_results($conn)) {
          printf("-------------\n");
        }
         //Prepare next result set
      } while (mysqli_next_result($conn));
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Android Studio?

Comment: **NEVER USE `mysqli_multi_query()`**

Comment: This a low-level app project sql injection arent really a concern? What do you suggest using@Dharman